# Html Css how to make shadow on overlay

Tags: html, css

i want to make a shadow on overlay of div like the shadow in the photo [image: photo]

***my code:***

```css
.nav-open {
    height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-open"></div>
```

**output:**
[image]

Comment: Can you kindly edit your code snippets so that they could work on our devices as well?

Answer (score 4):

Use `filter: brightness(50%)`. Everything in the div will be darkened.

Example with `filter: brightness(50%)`:

[image]

Example with `filter: brightness(150%)`:

[image]

Comment: where should i put it on the same div or on the div in the back?

Comment: On the div that contains the elements that you want to darken.

Comment: This deserves more upvotes. Also consider adding these properties for disabled overlay.
```user-select: none;
cursor: not-allowed;```